# Get the ID of a button from view to javascript?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have a button inside the view and I want to trigger this button inside a javascript file.

But the problem is, The ID of the button is referenced to the value of a Model.

In **VIEW**, I have this button.

```
 <button  id="update_@Model.UserLists[i].UserID" value="@Model.UserLists[i].UserID" class="btn btn-success">編集</button>
```

I want to trigger this button inside my **JS** File like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $("#update_@Model.UserLists[i].UserID").click(function() {

   });
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this goal? How can I do this, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an `onclick` event in your HTML button and trigger it. When using the `onclick` event with a function, you can access the values like `id` and `value`  as well. So, you can get the dynamic values parsed through the model.

```js
function update_Model(event){
  console.log(event.id);
}
```

```html
 <button  id="update_@Model.UserLists[i].UserID" value="@Model.UserLists[i].UserID" class="btn btn-success" onclick="update_Model(this)">編集</button>
```